# Why isn't recommended to use time-based blind for bruceforcing table/column names?

Tags: sql-injection

When not having priveleges on the session user you're using with sqlmap this warning appears when trying to retrieve table/column names, offering you to brute force names using a dictionary file,

```
do you want to use common column existence check? [y/N/q] y
[03:37:06] [WARNING] it's not recommended to use 'AND/OR time-based blind' and/or 'stacked queries' for common column existence check
are you sure you want to continue? [y/N]
```

Why isn't it recommended?

Comment: Could you please tag with the software you're using? / explicate the context of the question? This question makes little sense to people not into pentesting.

Comment: Isn't that true of most the questions on this site?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is [the condition that causes the warning](https://github.com/sqlmapproject/sqlmap/blob/master/lib/techniques/brute/use.py) to be shown:

```
if kb.columnExistsChoice is None and not any(_ for _ in kb.injection.data if _ not in (PAYLOAD.TECHNIQUE.TIME, PAYLOAD.TECHNIQUE.STACKED)) and not conf.direct:
```

The individual conditions mean:

- `kb.columnExistsChoice is None` – previous answer to the subsequent question "are you sure you want to continue?"
- `not any(_ for _ in kb.injection.data if _ not in (PAYLOAD.TECHNIQUE.TIME, PAYLOAD.TECHNIQUE.STACKED))` – whether there is no other injection using a technique other than time-based or stacked
- `not conf.direct` – whether it’s not a direct connection

So in conclusion, the warning is shown if

- it hasn’t been shown yet, and
- there is no other injection using a technique other than time-based or stacked, and
- it is not a direct connection.

The reason for that is probably because the time-based and stacked techniques are time consuming and may take quite a time to finish.